# How does the Web Addin project supports ECMAScript 2015 functions such as arrow function

Tags: office-js

One of my third party library uses arrow function and my current web addin project is not supporting it. I am using version 1 of office js (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js).

What changes I need to do in my current project to support ECMAScript 2015 functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to transpile the library's code down to ES5 JavaScript. The two best known transpilers are **tsc** and **babel**. Use WebPack to orchestrate the process of transpiling all the source files and bundling them into one or more JavaScript files that you load in the browser.